# Spring Boot Persistence

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

How does SpringBoot fetch the DataSource configuration from application.properties file.

Would the below configuration persist the entity  ?

Module 1 contains Config file and application.properties file

Module 2 contains Repository and Service File

I have not configured any File with @Repository annotation as of now.

contextRepository.saveAndFlush(test);

Spring Boot Configuration class below:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"ch.service"})
public class MyCodeConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

//Module1
package ch.service.config;

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource realDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class)
public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(realDataSource());
    return transactionManager;
}


}
```

Service Class below.

```
 //Module2
 package ch.service.config;

@Service
public class CodeServiceImpl implements CodeService {

@Autowired
private ContextRepository contextRepository;


@Transactional
public void persistValues(Testbean test){
      contextRepository.saveAndFlush(test);
  }

}
```

Repository class below

```
 //Module2
 package ch.service.config.dao;

public interface ContextRepository extends JpaRepository<MyContext, Long> {

}
```

Error Below:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method transactionManager in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.BitronixJtaConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'narayanaTransactionManager' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction', 'org.jboss.tm.XAResourceRecoveryRegistry'
```

Action:

```
Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager' in your configuration.
```

Comment: what's up with the package declaration inside of the Config class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **Spring Boot** you can use the following predefined DB configuration keys in **application.properties** to automatically configure the database.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Your rest of the code looks good. It should persist the data

To fix the Exception you are getting you have to have a Transaction Manager in your config.

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}
```

Ref : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: Thanks Avinash for the reply..2 questions I have in mind.. How is contextRepository able to persist here, as there is no explicit DB configuration?  .. Is the Datasource configured in MyCodeConfiguration  implicitly connected to contextRepository ..

Comment: The datasource is configured automatically once you define the above properties, this is a feature of Spring Boot. For those properties you don't have to do anything in MyCodeConfiguration class.

Comment: Is it possible to define a TransactionManager without defining the Bean in the above manner.. I mean via application.properties file configuration ..

Answer (score 0):

If your project has a data starter, for example :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And you want it to be connected to a non embedded database, you must setup the configuration in application.properties with `spring.datasource.*` keys

[DataSourceProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java) will pick up the configuration

All the spring boot key are [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: I have this depedency in my pom .. But getting the error :  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':

Comment: Could you provide the full log please ?

Comment: I have pasted the error in my post.. I was unable to post here due to length constraints ..